# Display default image when missing file in nginx

Tags: nginx

We have various pictures associated with items on our site but not for all of them. To this end we would like to display the contents of 'blank.jpg' if a given image is not found.

To this end we have the nginx config like this

```
location /static/images/ {
    root /blah_blah_blah/pictures/;
    error_page 404 blank.jpg;
    break;
}
```

The problems with this is that this takes /static/images/fred.jpg and redirects to /static/images/blank.jpg when what we want is to simply display the contents of blank.jpg whilst keeping the /static/images/fred.jpg url

It also seems to go into a redirect loop occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need it 10 month later but this looks like what you were looking for: https://serverfault.com/questions/562269/redirect-missing-images-in-a-specific-directory

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I am looking for (despite having implemented an ugly hack for this since posting).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share a little bit more sophisticated example. It's a way how you can match only selected extensions or name patterns:

```
location ~ ^/media/(.*)/preview(.*).(png|mp4)$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/media/(.*)/preview(.*).(png|mp4)$ $scheme://$host/media/no_preview/preview$2.$3 redirect;
}
```